# Power transform before aggregating data: benefits and risks

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, data-transformation, standardization, boxplot

I have several physiological recordings from different users, for example heart rate. I would like to aggregate these time-series into a single "metric". Let's say that I want to apply the mean function across testers for each time sample so that I obtain the average heart rate for all the users within a certain period of time.

In order to remove/minimize individual differences among users' recordings, because each user has a slightly different heart rate pattern, I am standardizing each time-series beforehand (removing the mean and dividing by the standard deviation).

The problem: the distribution of the recordings is not Gaussian. It is similar to a Poisson distribution with lambda=1. I suspect that I should not use Gaussian stats if the distribution is another one, in particular computing the average across recordings (testers).

[image]
*Left: original distribution, right: transformed distribution.*

Questions:

- Can I ignore the fact that the distributions are not Gaussian and go
  on with the procedure of standardizing each recording beforehand?
- If not, is it a good idea to use the power transform before standardizing the data to make it Gaussian?
- If yes to the latter, can I use a different power transform parameter for each recording, calculated with the Box-Cox algorithm,
  and compute the average across testers afterwards?

Altering the data (power transform) sounds "dangerous" to me since I am not an expert in statistics and I am afraid that I could be missing/misunderstanding important concepts here.